# how to check if network connection is valid in android?

Tags: android, networking, connection

I am using some code to detect network state and it works fine but sometimes the device is connected to wi-fi network but actually there is no internet .. i mean it is connected to router but the line is not working .. for example, when telephone line is cut off .. something like that .. 
now how can i detect that ??

This is my code :-

```
 public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null)
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null)
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
```

Comment: The only reliable way to determine whether you can connect to an internet site is to send a packet there and see if you get a response.

Comment: In the rare cases that your method returns true without a valid internet connection. You methods using internet resources should throw an exception by timeout or the like. That is, lazily be aware of the fact that the user is not online. That being said, having isConnectingToInternet() as a minimum before even attempting to use the internet makes perfect sense.

Comment: can you provide me with some code please?